# get first levels of Raster Data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a huge raster tif file 40GB, when I use this file in ArcMap it is very slow, I want to use this file only for the first levels, so I don't care about resolution. I don't want a compression I just want to reduce the resolution of the TIF. The tif has 0.3 cell size

Comment: What precisely have you tried?  Also, your question has a tag for [tag:gdal] but you make to mention of that in your question body, so can you [edit] your question to either remove it or explain its relevance, please?

Answer (score 3):

Check this here is one discussion about reducing size of tiff images. 
http://www.cvisiontech.com/library/file-formats/tiff/reduce-tiff-file-size.html

or You can use this
• Flatten your layers if any. 
• Use LZW compression to reduce tiff file size. 
• For pdf, try experimenting with compression settings in the Distiller job options.

Answer (score 0):

```
gdalwarp -tr xres yres in.tif out.tif
```

If you have gdal >= 2.0 [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) will automatically use the closest overview level to the target resolution.  If not it will resample from the full res image.